# Ubuntu VM's Already Made

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Does anyone know where you can get an Ubuntu 11.0 VM already created?  I am trying to test Ubuntu in Virtual Box and didn't want to have to go through an install it there is Vm's already created.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't be *Lazy*, just get the ISO, wait for it to download, Install Virtualbox, Install Ubuntu and it's done what's so difficult about it?. The VDI for VBox is going to be some ~4GB why downlaod that much when you can just downlaod less than 700MB?.

Comment: It isn't being lazy it is being efficient. Don't want to waste the time, if one is already ready to go.  Time is money, apparently you ain't got a clue.

Comment: OK, have fun downloading the 4gb VDi :)

Comment: @UriHerrera Is there a better option (besides downloading a pre-confugured VM) if you want to obtain an Ubuntu installation with a custom configuration and custom set of installed software?

Comment: @AndersonGreen you can easily customize an Ubuntu ISO and have the settings and software you would need.

Comment: @UriHerrera How can this be done, specifically?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Check on the questions with remaster in the tag or title.

Comment: @UriHerrera Where can I find "the question with remaster in the tag or title?" I don't see it on this page, so I'm not sure which specific question you're referring to.

Comment: @AndersonGreen On the top-right of the site there is a search box , search for remaster ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to download a preconfigured virtual machine for Virtual Box e.g. from

### [Virtual Boxes](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/)

At present a compressed image for Ubuntu 11.10 x86 is 608 MB, slightly less than a real installation CD.

However as was already said in comments I personally **do not recommed** to do so for several good reasons:

- it is a **security issue** because there is no way to find out what the person who set up the machine may have installed in addition.
- you can but you can not so easily **customize your Ubuntu** users (admin users, password, locale etc.) after the initial installation has been done.
- There is no easy way to change the **size of the virtual hard drive** for your personal needs.
- In case you need to reinstall or configure the virtual machine you will need to have **access to a "live" environment**, which is not provided with the image you downloaded.

Installing Ubuntu is an **extremely** easy task that will take you less than 20 minutes. This is also true when installing in a virtual machine. Therefore there is no good reason (not even being lazy) to not install Ubuntu directly.

For testing you could even boot your virtual machine to an Ubuntu live environment from the installation CD .iso **without installation** in a minute (but then you will not have benefits from Guest Additions)

> **In summary:** you do not need a preconfigured virtual machine for testing Ubuntu.

Comment: You know, the difference between market-dominating projects like the Linux kernel, MS Windows and others to niche projects like most Linux distros (Ubuntu included, sadly) is that they don't tell users what they need, they ask users what they want.

Answer (score 3):

Installing Ubuntu on (for example) Virtual Box is quite easy :]
And it is really worth trying.

Comment: Thanks...  So I guess no one on the internet has Virtual machines per-configured.  Guess will download.

Comment: It doesn't take too much time - at least in my opinion. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami.org has preconfigured Ubuntu LAMP Stacks (http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/virtual-machine). However, these come configured with several extra apps and in a slightly odd configuration. I use them for testing apps and playing with different concepts. But for production environments I typically start from scratch with the latest Ubuntu LTS iso.

Answer (score 0):

they do now, at least Ubuntu does, check their download page

sun also has premade VMs on their page

As far as "security issues" arising from not knowing who did what in the code, isn't that what AI virus-scanners are for? :)

Comment: "*check their download page*" is vague. Maybe folks will go to the wrong page (there are several possibile). Consider adding a link to the page, and perhaps another example link to a VM image.