# Installing Ubuntu server to Virtual box

Tags: installation, server, virtualbox

I would like to install Ubuntu Server 10.04-2.7z which i downloaded from sourceforge, as i was downloading, i googled for an iso image of the OS so even though there was no .iso, i assumed it was an image, however , when i am installing the image on virtual box, the first discrepency i notice is that when i click on storage,on CONTROLLER:IDE, i see Host Drive:E instead of EMPTY which is on all the tutorials i have followed. And then when i click on add virtual cd/dvd disk file, the file that i have extracted to my desktop doesnt do anything when i click on it. This is the data about the OS i installed

> ```
> Ubuntu Linux Server Edition 10.04.2 LTS x86
> Size (compressed/uncompressed): 295.04 MB/1.3 GB
> Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualboximage/files/UbuntuServer/10.04.2/Ubuntu_server_10-04-2.7z/download
> Active user account(s) (username/password): ubuntu/reverse
> Notes: Guest Additions not installed ; meta-package build-essential installed.
> ```

I am using Oracle Virtual Box 4.3.6-9140.Win-exe. I am sorry the questionmay not be quite clear without screenshots, but any help will be truly appreciated

Comment: .7z is a compressed file. Unzip the file and use it as a hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded an image of a ready made virtual machine for use in Virtual  Box. Such an image may save you some time with installing and configuring but this advantage is of short sight. It is not really recommended to so so ([for reasons outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99466/ubuntu-vms-already-made)).

Only after you had installed Ubuntu by yourself (which should not take much time) you will be sure that drives, permissions, and installed applications will meet your needs. A fresh installation of Ubuntu will be "ready to go". You will find all applications needed for first steps to configure your server. Additional applications can quickly be downloaded from the Ubuntu repositories.

You can download the unmodified original CD-ROM .iso file for installation of Ubuntu 10.04 server in Virtual Box here:

- [Ubuntu Old Releases 10.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.3/)

Note that the support for 10.04 server edition will **end in April 2015**. In case you need a support longer than this (April 2017) you may want to consider to download the much more up to date long term release Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from:

- [Ubuntu Releases: 12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/)